# Grand Sum of Rows and Columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table like below.

```
Year          AccountGroupA   AccountGroup B   RowSum
2004                 15                 23       38
2005                 10                 10       20
2006                  8                 15       23
2007                 16                 14       30
ColumnSum            49                 62      111
```

I need grand sum of rows and colums ex:- I need result as 111 in sql query.

The Result needs to be returned from a sql function so ideally should be a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select year, 
       sum(accountGroupA) as accountGroupA, 
       sum(AccountGroupB)as accountGroupb, 
       sum(accountGroupA + AccountGroupB) as rowsum
from the_table
group by year with rollup
```

This assumes that you only have one row per year or if you have more than one that you actually want to group by year. If neither is the case, you can use a union to achieve the same:

```
select year, accountGroupA, AccountGroupB, rowsum
from (
  select year, accountGroupA, AccountGroupB, accountGroupA + AccountGroupB as rowsum, 0 as union_order
  from the_table
  union all
  select null, sum(accountGroupA), sum(AccountGroupB), sum(accountGroupA + AccountGroupB), 1 
  from the_table
) t
order by union_order, year
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd4bc/2

Answer (score 0):

For the ColumnSum the SQL is easy:

```
SELECT sum(AccountGroupA), sum(AccountGroupB) from YOUR_TABLE
```

The row sums have to be coded like this:

```
SELECT (AccountGroupA + AccountGroupB) as RowSum from YOUR_TABLE
```

Forget about getting the desired result in one SQL statment. Although that is certainly possible with a nasty nested SQL I would not recommend it.

Comment: I need to return this result from a function so I would bascially need it as a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the ROLLUP Operator.

MSDN Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx

I've created a SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df41d/7

More specifically, the code is here:

```
select 
   case when (Grouping(Year)) = 1 
         then 'ColumnSum' 
         else isnull(Year, 'Unknown') end as Year,
   sum(AccountGroupA) as AccountGroupA,
   sum(AccountGroupB) as AccountGroupB,
   sum(AccountGroupA + AccountGroupB) as RowSum
from TestTable
  group by Year with ROLLUP
```